# Iphone notifications and Arduino

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, arduino

I'm working on a project with Arduino and ios . I want to create an app , which is able to change the color of a rgb strip attached to Arduino , depending on the notifications that arrive on the iPhone . I want to know how is it possible to understand such notifications arrive . for example I want that if I get a notification from Facebook , the application sends a command to Arduino to turn on the blue LED etc ... you can distinguish the notifications that come to the iPhone in some way ??

Comment: You can't do this from ios directly since one app cannot access notifications for another app. You would need to add BLE capability to your Arduino and implement ANCS functionality in your Arduino. This is non-trivial since ANCS requires the Arduino to act as a central, not a peripheral which is the opposite to how most Arduino modules I have seen operate.